# Referencing Hid Library from GitHub library in C# and use it

Tags: c#, .net, github, usb, hid

I am just starting to learn C# so excuse me if this is a basic question. 
I am trying to develop an application that reads values for a USB-HID scale into Excel. To start I am going to use this github library (already downloaded it):
https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary
then use closedxml.codeplex.com to create a spreadsheet and transfer data there.

I am trying to figure out how to reference this library in my C# project and use it to get information from the scale. I don't know much about C# or .NET and would love some help, most google searches haven't helped much so any leads would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided from GitHub specifies the name of the lib for referenced it on your project. Take a look at the Installation section. This code is for using on the Nuget Package Console on your project.

```
PM> Install-Package hidlibrary
```

Take a look on how to use the Nuget Package console for Visual Studio on this link
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: That was useful, would you have resources that could help me use the HID library to connect to the scale and retrieve information

Comment: I'm glad to hearing from you @H.H. If this answer solves you problem please mark it as a valid answer.

Comment: well it only partially helped. I've got the library connected but I still do not know how to use the library to contact the HID device and retrieve information from it

Comment: For your next questions be more specific on the title, so users can help you on what you really want and also don't mix many questions on a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Hid.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net)

You can read about Hid transfer in the documentation [here](https://melbournedeveloper.github.io/Device.Net/articles/HidTransfer.html).

This reads from a thermometer which would probably be similar to scales.

[Reference](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/90aa91e584ec2f7e25002c157ad6bd42e87aa618/src/Usb.Net.WindowsSample/Program.cs#L117)

```
    private static async Task DisplayTemperature()
    {
        //Connect to the device by product id and vendor id
        var temperDevice = await new FilterDeviceDefinition(vendorId: 0x413d, productId: 0x2107, usagePage: 65280)
            .CreateWindowsHidDeviceFactory(_loggerFactory)
            .ConnectFirstAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        //Create the observable
        var observable = Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1))
            .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => temperDevice.WriteAndReadAsync(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x80, 0x33, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 })))
            .Select(data => (data.Data[4] & 0xFF) + (data.Data[3] << 8))
            //Only display the temperature when it changes
            .Distinct()
            .Select(temperatureTimesOneHundred => Math.Round(temperatureTimesOneHundred / 100.0m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven));

        //Subscribe to the observable
        _ = observable.Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine($"Temperature is {t}"));

        //Note: in a real scenario, we would dispose of the subscription afterwards. This method runs forever.
    }
```